# Symfony 5.2 - apache configuration doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I've created a Syfmony 5.2 project and on my local I've used `symfony serve -d`. So, when I've put the project live, I need an .htaccess file. Well, it looks like below:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

   
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**The result?**
`The page isn’t redirecting properly`

Please, can someone tell me what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html
I am not very familiar with Apache, I usually use NGINX but on first look, it looks like you need to define a document root to /var/www/project/public.
I hope you can move forward with this information.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I've added DocumentRoot, but now I receive 500, therefore a step forward was made. 
There is a way to see the errors from htaccess?

Comment: If the 500 is from Apache, you can define the error log path in .htaccess like: 

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

If the error comes from Symfony, you can see the logs in /var//www/project/var/log

Comment: ok. I've added also and still the same answer.

I have an htaccess (for the main project) good. And from what I see the only diference is that DocumentRoot (the project is on shared VPN), so it is possible to not see the all path for that.

Without that, i see in logs that he enter in code ... 
it can be from something else.